# why elasticsearch span_near like boolean query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use `span_near` query in `elasticsearch` but it doesn't meet my need exactly.
Using `span_near` all `span_terms` have to exists in the substring otherwise it actually ignore the doc, I want a query like `span_near` considering some score for docs having only some of the `span_terms`.
what should I do?

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "span_near": {
            "clauses": [
              {
                "span_term": {
                  "field": "term1"
                }
              },
              {
                "span_term": {
                  "field": "term2"
                }
              },
              {
                "span_term": {
                  "field": "term3"
                }
              }
            ],
            "slop": 10,
            "in_order": false,
            "boost" : 1
          }
        },
        ...
     ]
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

span_near itself does not have option you are looking for. You can add another match query in should clause which will return documents having any of the terms. Since span_near has higher boost, its documents will be scored higher.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "span_near": {
            "clauses": [
              {
                "span_term": {
                  "text": "term1"
                }
              },
              {
                "span_term": {
                  "text": "term2"
                }
              },
              {
                "span_term": {
                  "text": "term3"
                }
              }
            ],
            "slop": 10,
            "in_order": false,
            "boost": 5
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "text": "term1 term2 term3"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```